# using mongodb for building database with schema

Tags: java, mongodb

I am making a travel portal(airline booking site like make my trip...)

I wanted to use mongodb as database for it instead of mysql, mongodb is schemaless and my mentor told me not every database can be used for every application, but why, its just a database, we perform CRUD operation and use it?

Comment: Your mentor is correct that different databases have different advantages and disadvantages and thus different use cases they're appropriate for. Whether Mongo is appropriate for your particular project depends on a lot more info than you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A finer answer to your question would involve explaining things that make up the database. Not every database (not necessarily relational) has the features mentioned below

- Eventual consistency
- Referential integrity
- Linking between objects
- Metadata attached to data objects
- In-built Sharding through hashing
- Transaction isloation
- ... and so on

An application should use a database that best helps it perform its *raison d'etre*. There is no single database that can fit the bill for all use cases. In fact certain no-sql stores do not even have a concept of 'transactions'.